# setGravity in code not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

In program I have `EditText`. I want, set text `Gravity` in code:

```
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    int size = 40;
    TableLayout tl;
    tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
    TableRow tr;
    tr = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow);

    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.height = size;
    params.width = size;
    et.setLayoutParams(params);
    et.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    et.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    et.setTextSize(size - size / 4);
    et.setText("3");
    tr.addView(et);
}
```

My XML:

```
<TableLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/layout"
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

but, on the screen I can see:

[image]

How can I set Text gravity(horizonally and vertically) in code?

Comment: You should use the virtual phones software provided by google then you have more info debugging your layout. Do you have the same problem with a static layout. Maybe you can better use the screen shot functionality. Instead of putting your phone on a scanner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

Try to set `Gravity` for both `TableLayout` and `TableRow`

```
tl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: Your idea set in the middle editText on the screen. I just want center text(number) on the editText.

Comment: @user3483899 just use `et.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);`

Comment: et.setGravity(Gravity.Center);
gave same effect as on the picture.

Comment: @user3483899 give the EditText height and width specific and try like height=50 and width = 100

Answer (score 1):

You can set the gravity on your layout parameters as well:

```
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your xml to the question? The elements react differently to different kinds of layouts. Even if you specify that gravity if you don't have the proper layout it won't move.